# Is a function $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ which has a closed and connected graph necessarily continuous?

Tags: general-topology

It has been proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1709749/444923) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3815106/444923) that a function
$\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which has a closed and connected graph is continuous.
This fact is also proved in [a nice article by Burgess](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2324521). I don't know how to generalize these proofs to the case of a function
$\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, $n \ge 2$, however. Is a function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ which has a closed and connected graph necessarily continuous?

The following fact, which is stated in Munkres (Exercise 26.8), may be useful. For a topological space $X$ and compact Hausdorff space $Y$, a function $X \to Y$ is continuous if and only if its graph is a closed subset of $X \times Y$. So it would be enough to show that the function $f$ is bounded on compact sets.

Comment: For those wondering whether closure of the graph is necessary, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3273874/can-a-nowhere-continuous-function-have-a-connected-graph

Comment: For Munkres's exercise see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1769333.

Comment: The answer is no. [A counterexample on $\mathbb R^2$.](https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/702089/ActaCarolinae_044-2003-2_8.pdf)

Comment: @Ricky Will you post this as an answer? I will try to understand it better before accepting, but it looks like a great answer to me.

Comment: It is true under some homological assumptions on the graph, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366747/if-the-graph-gf-of-f-a-b-rightarrow-mathbbr-is-path-connected-th/2577434#2577434